# Shepherdson's model for Open Induction

Tags: reference-request, logic, arithmetic, model-theory

In the paper "A Non-Standard Model for a Free Variable Fragment of Number Theory", Shepherdson constructs a recursive model for a fragment of arithmetic known as "Open Induction". I would like to learn the construction but the paper seems hardly available. Does anyone knows where the paper can be found or does anyone knows an alternative (available) source in which the Shepherdson-construction is explained?

What I have found out so far is that the following theorem seems essential for the construction of Shepherdson's model:

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ Let $R$ be a discretely ordered ring and let $F$ denote the real closure of its field of fractions. Then, $R$ is a model of open induction iff $R$ is an integral part of $F$.

I did not found a source containing the proof of this theorem, so I am trying to prove it by myself but I have no idea where to start. It will also be helpful to me if someone can provide me some hints or a sketch of the proof (presupposed it is not too long and complicated to be stated here). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.researchgate.net/publication/244963704_A_Non-Standard_Model_for_a_Free_Variable_Fragment_of_Number_Theory

Comment: @MJay1985: I tried it but I see the message:  "The full-text for this publication is not yet available on ResearchGate." I just requested the paper but I am unsure whether the request will be successful. Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: Does your university have acess to JSTOR? http://www.jstor.org/stable/2269666?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @MJay1985. I have already seen this one. It is only a short review article but not the original paper I am looking for.

Comment: It seems that the journal was last published in 1978. So there is little chance of finding the original article digitally. However some libraries will have physical copies in their archives. I'll be back at my uni in 2 weeks. If you don't find it by then, let me know and I'll try to get a copy and scan it for you.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan: Thanks for this nice offer!

Comment: I am looking for the same article. Did you find it and if so do you have a digital copy?

Comment: @AndersLundstedt: I did not find the article. Sorry.

Comment: I have now obtained a copy of the article, which I can provide to anyone interested.

Comment: @AndersLundstedt I'd be interested in a copy!